# Ignore request for parallel computation if a function lower in stack already ignites parallel computation

Tags: multithreading, openmp

Is it possible with OpenMP, when a function, lower in stack, ignites multiprocessing, then OpenMP facilites ignore multiprocessing requests from functions' bodies, higher in stack?

Is this the way OpenMP always works? If not, can I do this? How?

```
void do1()
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i);
}
void do2()
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) do1();
}
void do3()
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) do2();
}
int main()
{
    do1(); // runs in parallel
    do2(); // do2() runs in parallel, do1() I want not
    do3(); // do3() runs in parallel, do1() and do2() I want not
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenMP works exactly as you described, if nested parallelism is disabled. On current OpenMP implementations it is disabled by default, but it is not specified by the standard, so to be on the safe side it is worth disabling it by setting [`OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse56.html#x295-20660006.8) environmental variable to 1 or by using [`omp_set_max_active_levels(1);`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu125.html#x162-7300003.2.16) function in your code.

Answer (score 2):

This situation is called nesting and it is generally inefficient (this is dependent of the runtime though). You can tweak OpenMP runtime parameter to mitigate performance issue (see the answer of @Laci), but honestly, this pattern often causes more issues than it solves. The modern solution is simply to **use tasks** and more specifically `taskloop` directives in your case. Alternatively, you can use the `if(...)` clause to tune the parallel section behaviour (eg. disable parallelism regarding a given condition). The scheduling of the task is dependent of the runtime. For example, IOMP (Clang/ICC) is based on a (randomized) work-stealing algorithm while GCC use a bounded centralized queue. The overhead of tasks can be bigger than the one of parallel sections (especially with a static scheduling).

Note that the stack frame can be optimized by compilers. In fact, `do1`, `do2` and `do3` can be inlined so that at runtime there is no trace left of theses functions.

Comment: I agree with you, but in some cases (e.g. using a library) you may not be able to control it. What kind of issues can be expected in this situation (i.e. both your code and the library use OpenMP)?

Comment: I agree. In one case there is generally an over-subscription issue or at best an overhead due to many new sections to be created (synchronizations and ICV init overheads). In the other case, tasks can be problematic on NUMA system (typically due to a bad scheduling or no information for the runtime to schedule that properly). After a decade of research, the nesting problem is I think a dead end, but efficient tasking is challenging (there is a lot of research on it, especially quite recently).

Comment: It is not rare for people to try tasks and be disappointed by the resulting performance. The thing is tasks-based programs are often easier to compose than ones based on basic fork-join. Thus, the benefit of tasks is often delayed (assuming libraries one support tasks) while the one of fork-join section is often immediate. Library writers do not see the "big picture" and application writers are not aware of the implementation details. This problem is similar to the local VS global optimization problem. (Disclaimer: I worked on OpenMP tasks in the past ;) ).

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Does using a very general `if(!omp_in_parallel())` clause in `do1` and `do2` functions make any sense? Does it reduce overheads? (My guess is not, but I do not know how OpenMP runtimes work)

Comment: The `if(...)` clause is often surprisingly slower than a basic encompassing conditional statement based on my past experiments (few years ago). This is sad because in pathological cases, this encourage users to duplicate the code (version with/without OpenMP). I would not be surprised to see that this is faster to use basic conditional statement rather than letting runtimes do the job automatically for fork-join section too. AFAIR this was due to a late decision in functions of the runtime. This is only a problem for sections called a lot of time (which is a sign of an inefficient execution).